# Connecting to different LAN through raspberry pi

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, port-forwarding, lan

I have a raspberry pi, which is connected to a local network, let's say LAN1. I also have a desktop, which is connected to a different local network, LAN2. Both the raspberry pi and the desktop have access to the internet. I would like to have access to LAN1 from my desktop, but ssh is not an option because of the low processing power of the raspberry pi. Essentially I want to forward all traffic through the raspberry pi. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks for any answers in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The Raspberry Pi should have enough processing power to handle ssh, so that's not the issue.

Nevertheless, the way you usually do that is to make a VPN (virtual private network) connection by running one server on the desktop and RaspPi each, and then you setup the RaspPi so it forwards traffic from and to LAN2 through the VPN.

A populare software package for that is OpenVPN, google for tutorials how to set it up.